# when a CPR (Central Pivot Range) extends the CPR lines to the right of the chart horizontally when the price doesn't touch the CPR level

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

```
//@version=4
study("Extended Central Pivot Range virgin(CPR)", overlay=true)

// Input for transparency
transparency = input(80, title="Transparency", minval=0, maxval=100)

// CPR Calculation
cprRange = high - low
pivot = (high + low + close) / 3
cprHigh = pivot + cprRange
cprLow = pivot - cprRange

// Determine if price doesn't touch CPR level
priceDoesNotTouchCPR = close < cprLow or close > cprHigh

// Plotting CPR levels with different transparencies
plot(cprHigh, title="CPR High", color=color.blue, linewidth=2, transp=priceDoesNotTouchCPR ? 0 : transparency)
plot(cprLow, title="CPR Low", color=color.blue, linewidth=2, transp=priceDoesNotTouchCPR ? 0 : transparency)

// Extend CPR lines to the right of the chart
cprHighExt = valuewhen(priceDoesNotTouchCPR, cprHigh, 0)
cprLowExt = valuewhen(priceDoesNotTouchCPR, cprLow, 0)
plot(cprHighExt, title="CPR High Extended", color=color.blue, linewidth=2, transp=na, offset=1)
plot(cprLowExt, title="CPR Low Extended", color=color.blue, linewidth=2, transp=na, offset=1)
```

im facing some errors which im not able to solve need some help

> 4:23:07 PM Error at 17:0 Cannot call 'plot' with 'transp'=series[integer]. The argument should be of type: input integer;
> 4:23:07 PM Error at 18:0 Cannot call 'plot' with 'transp'=series[integer]. The argument should be of type: input integer